# Flutter BLE connection

Tags: flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have the below code. When i run the scan, it seems to fail to find the device. Device name and service uuid are correct.
Since most of the ble side has been put together from examples i've found, i feel like there's a difference between what i'm trying to achieve and what the example coder was.

Should i continue down this route or try a search, list devices and click for preferred device type connection?

Any advice would be great.
Very new to this and just trying to learn.

I've marked in the code where i think it's failing.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io' show Platform;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_gauges/gauges.dart';
import 'package:location_permissions/location_permissions.dart';
import 'package:flutter_reactive_ble/flutter_reactive_ble.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool switchstate = false;
  double sliderval = 0.0;
  int intsliderval = 0;
  // Some state management stuff
  bool _foundDeviceWaitingToConnect = false;
  bool _scanStarted = false;
  bool _connected = false;
// Bluetooth related variables
  late DiscoveredDevice _bleDevice;
  final flutterReactiveBle = FlutterReactiveBle();
  late StreamSubscription<DiscoveredDevice> _scanStream;
  late QualifiedCharacteristic _rxCharacteristic;
// These are the UUIDs of your device
  Uuid serviceUuid = Uuid.parse("4fafc201-1fb5-459e-8fcc-c5c9c331914b");
  Uuid characteristicUuid = Uuid.parse("3c65eaf2-c20d-495c-81f6-6032fab36737");

  void _startScan() async {
// Platform permissions handling stuff
    bool permGranted = false;
    setState(() {
      _scanStarted = true;
    });
    PermissionStatus permission;
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      permission = await LocationPermissions().requestPermissions();
      if (permission == PermissionStatus.granted) permGranted = true;
    } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
      permGranted = true;
    }
    print("started");
    print(permGranted);
// Main scanning logic happens here ⤵️
    if (permGranted) {
      _scanStream = flutterReactiveBle // Seems to fail here :(
          .scanForDevices(withServices: [serviceUuid]).listen((device) {
        if (device.name == "ESP32") {
          setState(() {
            _bleDevice = device;
            _foundDeviceWaitingToConnect = true;
            print("found");
            print(_foundDeviceWaitingToConnect);
          });
        } else {
          print("not found");
        }
      });
    }
  }

  void _connectToDevice() {
    // We're done scanning, we can cancel it
    _scanStream.cancel();
    // Let's listen to our connection so we can make updates on a state change
    Stream<ConnectionStateUpdate> _currentConnectionStream = flutterReactiveBle
        .connectToAdvertisingDevice(
            id: _bleDevice.id,
            prescanDuration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
            withServices: [serviceUuid, characteristicUuid]);
    _currentConnectionStream.listen((event) {
      switch (event.connectionState) {
        // We're connected and good to go!
        case DeviceConnectionState.connected:
          {
            _rxCharacteristic = QualifiedCharacteristic(
                serviceId: serviceUuid,
                characteristicId: characteristicUuid,
                deviceId: event.deviceId);
            setState(() {
              _foundDeviceWaitingToConnect = false;
              _connected = true;
            });
            break;
          }
        // Can add various state state updates on disconnect
        case DeviceConnectionState.disconnected:
          {
            break;
          }
        default:
      }
    });
  }

  void _adjustLED(double) {
    intsliderval = sliderval.toInt();
    if (_connected) {
      flutterReactiveBle
          .writeCharacteristicWithResponse(_rxCharacteristic, value: [
        intsliderval,
      ]);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
          // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
          title: Text(
        widget.title,
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      )),
      body: Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child: Column(
          // Column is also a layout widget. It takes a list of children and
          // arranges them vertically. By default, it sizes itself to fit its
          // children horizontally, and tries to be as tall as its parent.
          //
          // Invoke "debug painting" (press "p" in the console, choose the
          // "Toggle Debug Paint" action from the Flutter Inspector in Android
          // Studio, or the "Toggle Debug Paint" command in Visual Studio Code)
          // to see the wireframe for each widget.
          //
          // Column has various properties to control how it sizes itself and
          // how it positions its children. Here we use mainAxisAlignment to
          // center the children vertically; the main axis here is the vertical
          // axis because Columns are vertical (the cross axis would be
          // horizontal).
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: <Widget>[
            SfRadialGauge(
              axes: <RadialAxis>[
                RadialAxis(
                    minimum: -10,
                    maximum: 60,
                    interval: 10,
                    pointers: <GaugePointer>[
                      RangePointer(
                        value: 28,
                        enableAnimation: true,
                      )
                    ],
                    annotations: <GaugeAnnotation>[
                      GaugeAnnotation(widget: Text("28"))
                    ])
              ],
            ),
            Text(
              "LED",
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 18,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: Colors.blue),
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              children: <Widget>[
                Switch(
                    value: switchstate,
                    onChanged: (bool s) {
                      setState(() {
                        switchstate = s;
                      });
                    }),
                Flexible(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Slider(
                    value: switchstate ? sliderval : 0,
                    onChanged: (sliderval) => setState(
                      () => this.sliderval = sliderval,
                    ),
                    onChangeEnd: _adjustLED,
                    min: 0,
                    max: 100,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      persistentFooterButtons: [
        // We want to enable this button if the scan has NOT started
        // If the scan HAS started, it should be disabled.
        _scanStarted
            // True condition
            ? ElevatedButton(
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  primary: Colors.grey, // background
                  onPrimary: Colors.white, // foreground
                ),
                onPressed: () {},
                child: const Icon(Icons.search),
              )
            // False condition
            : ElevatedButton(
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  primary: Colors.blue, // background
                  onPrimary: Colors.white, // foreground
                ),
                onPressed: _startScan,
                child: const Icon(Icons.search),
              ),
        _foundDeviceWaitingToConnect
            // True condition
            ? ElevatedButton(
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  primary: Colors.blue, // background
                  onPrimary: Colors.white, // foreground
                ),
                onPressed: _connectToDevice,
                child: const Icon(Icons.bluetooth),
              )
            // False condition
            : ElevatedButton(
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  primary: Colors.grey, // background
                  onPrimary: Colors.white, // foreground
                ),
                onPressed: () {},
                child: const Icon(Icons.bluetooth),
              ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

This is what comes up in the console so it does seem to be scanning and finding devices (i think):

```
I/flutter (25082): started
I/flutter (25082): true
D/BluetoothAdapter(25082): STATE_ON
I/chatty  (25082): uid=10169(com.example.new_try) pool-1-thread-1 identical 4 lines
D/BluetoothAdapter(25082): STATE_ON
D/BluetoothLeScanner(25082): Start Scan with callback
D/BluetoothLeScanner(25082): onScannerRegistered() - status=0 scannerId=9 mScannerId=0
```

Comment: Are you trying to run this application in Emulator and scan for bluetooth devices? If so, the emulator does not support bluetooth testing. You need to use a physical device for debugging.

Comment: No. Running on a physical device. I’ve run npf connect on the device also and it detect and connect to the device.